# Which class of functions can be represented as $F(z)=\int A(t)z^t dt$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

If I have a *holomorphic* function $f(z)$, then I can write it as $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n.$$ So these functions can be viewed as a generating function of the coefficients $\{a_n\}$ which have a certain structure. There are nice finite differential problems, solved exactly by some sequences $\{a_n\}$ encoded in a generating function. From what I see, they are like a set of numbers with incredibly low Kolmogorov complexity (see comments). The property of being holomorphic is tied to the derivation $f'(z)$ being defined/existent/computable for the function. And this derivation is also used in the "algorithm" for generating the $a_n$'s, namely the series expansion. Is this a valuable perspective?

In this same vain, I wonder if there is a class of functions, let's denote one by $F$, for which there are unique $A$, such that

$$F(z)=\int A(t)z^t\ \mathbb{d}t.$$

Thoughts: This reminds me of the Laplace transform, which is essentiall the same thing, only with $z\equiv\mathbb{e}^{-s}$. Hence, in the sense of the discussion abov, $F(z)$ would encode information $A(t)$, which solves some problem. One of my motivations really is just to understand the Laplace transform better. Some differential equations are solved via Laplace transform, but to see how their information relates to the differential equations is not so straight forward to me as in the case with the countable series expansion numbers $a_n$. I assume there must be something coming from the fact that the exponential function is tied to the derivative operation.

Trying to "grok it", I've come across some (category theoretical) approaches to these integral transforms, which reseble the Pontryagin duality construction. This approach seems sensible to me. (And after all, I find it kind of arbitrary that this theory is exclusively centered around the hom's to the circle group.)

Comment: I don't understand the first paragraph. What is the "certain structure"? What "incredibly low Kolmogorov complexity"?

Comment: @Ilya: That's just mean.

Comment: @NickKidman: I apologize then, but if it's not on purpose - it rather means that both the OP and the comments are written without being well-thought about, which is not something welcomed.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I mean the infinite number of coefficients $a_n$ can be encoded in one expresstion for the function, e.g. the string "$x/(1-x-x^2)$" as input for the "trylor expansion algorithm" generates the Fibinacci numbers $0,\;1,\;1,\;2,\;3,\;5,\;8,\;13,\;21,\;34,\;55,\;89,\;144$. All complex differentiable functions, i.e. all strings with which the algorithm could work with, generate some numbers $a_n$ this way.

Comment: @Ilya: That's kind of mean too, but I try to take it as constructive criticism.

Comment: @NickKidman: ok. Also note that deleting comments is neither a good way of doing things.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I should add that by "certain strucute" I also mean the relation between the numbers $a_n$, which make it even possible that all of them can be encoded in the expression for the generating function. E.g. the Fibinacci numbers solve the bunny population problem and the recursive relation is that structure. I view the series expansion algorithm $\text{algorithm}$ as the starting point so that "$\text{algorithm}(f_{\text{bunny}},n)\rightarrow a_n$". We search for $f_{\text{bunny}}$, abstracting from it being something which can be graphed, has something to do with complex numbers...

Comment: @Nick: the generating function of the Fibonacci numbers belongs to an extremely restricted class of functions (namely rational functions). A generic holomorphic function need not be anywhere near this nice. In particular, the sequence $a_n$ can have arbitrarily high Kolmogorov complexity or just be noncomputable (which is the generic case).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Mhm, aha okay. Does this imply that talking the n-th derivative and setting $z=z_0$ in the resulting expression is noncomputable? If not, I don't see why computing $a_n$ would be problematic. And if it's not possible, can't you use stalks and germs to reason about this function?

Comment: @Nick: most holomorphic functions do not have nice expressions that you can take derivatives of symbolically. You seem to still be thinking of something like an elementary function. The generic holomorphic function (in some neighborhood of the origin) is just specified by a sequence $a_n$ which is bounded by some exponential (so the series has a finite radius of convergence). The generic such sequence is not computable (there are uncountably many of them and only countably many computable sequences).

Comment: @Nick: in general I think the first half of this question is confused. Try to remove the unnecessary parts of the question; what remains seems to be a question about what functions are Laplace transforms, which seems fine.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Okay thanks for the warning, I'll look into it more. Some part of the question was really motivation.

Comment: What is the upper limit and the lower limit of the integral? Note that different upper limit and lower limit will influence the effect of the integral transform.

Comment: @doraemonpaul: Minus infty to plus infty was my initial thought, but yes, as I have no idea how this affects the possible answers, I left it open.